# Sending request to ASP.NET Core WebAPI hosted within Azure VM via url and port number

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have problem sending request to an ASP.NET Core WebAPI app hosted within Azure VM. The app is not reachable. The app has a port number, and its url is like below:

http://myapp.ukwest.cloudapp.azure.com:1234/

I added an inbound rule using below:

Go to the hosting VM -> Networking -> Add inbound rule -> specified 1234 for port number.

then restart the VM, but the url seems not working.

I tried the same inbound rule and hosted the same app in another VM, which works. It seems I am missing some settings on the first VM.

Any idea?

Comment: If you eliminate the rule and wait (1+ hours to be safe) are you still hitting the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be caused by the port being blocked by the internal firewall inside the VM, make sure you allowed that port there as well.

Hope it helps!